# how to show Related product in magento soap api V2

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I have written soap API for related product but this script is not working ,here is my code,i am totally new to this. please help me someone.Thanks

---

```
<?php 
// Get related products in productId
require_once('../app/Mage.php');//Path to Magento umask(0);

if(isset($_GET["productId"])){
  $categoryId=$_GET["productId"];
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http:/www.prashant.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('pras', 'prashant123@'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

    $products= $proxy->catalogProductLinkList($sessionId,$productId);


    $itemDetails=array();
    Mage::app(); 

  foreach ($products as $item) { 

    $product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->product_id);
    $productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
    $baseImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product2->getImage());
    $price2=0;
    $price2=$product2->getFinalPrice();
    if($price2==0){
    $price2=$product2->getPrice();
    }



    $desc=$product2->getDescription();
           if($desc==""){
            $desc="blank";
           }


           $baseImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product2->getImage());
           if($baseImageUrl=="http://www.prashant.com/media/catalog/product/"){
            $baseImageUrl="http://www.prashant.com/customApi/icon.png";
           }

           //"desc"=>$desc,

           $statusp=$product2->getStatus();
    $statusen= Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED;


    if($statusp==$statusen){
         $itemDetails[]=array(
      "productId"=>$item->product_id,
      "name"=>$product2->getName(),
      "price"=>$product2->getPrice(),
      "spprice"=>$price2,
      "desc"=>$desc,
      "imageurl"=>$baseImageUrl,
      );
    }


  }
  //return array of products
  //echo "<pre>";
  //print_r($itemDetails);
  //echo "</pre>";
  echo json_encode($itemDetails);
  exit();
}else{
  echo "error";
  exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server does not working, because this I can't test your code.

I made a simple try to get related products for product that ID is '45' and the code can be viewed below

```
    <?php

    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.uaiaquitem.com.br/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1'); // TODO : change url
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx'); // TODO : change login and pwd

    //$products= $proxy->catalogProductLinkList($sessionId,$productId);

    $result = $proxy->catalogProductLinkList($sessionId,  'related', '45', '1');

    var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not get related products directly though SOAP api, you need to create custom code for getting related product collection, here my ref.

```
<?php
    $productColection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $productColection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds())
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => $_REQUEST['product_id']));

    foreach ($productColection as $product)
    {
        $relatedIds = $product->getRelatedProductIds();
    }
    $relatedProductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $relatedProductCollection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds())
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $relatedIds))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
    foreach($relatedProductCollection as $related){
        echo $related->getName();
        -------------------
    }

?>
```